# Custom sort with series of numbers(sequences) using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table Abstract, which has one of the columns (SerialNumber). It is having data as below.

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.2
..
..
10
10.1
10.2
```

Now, my requirement is to sort the data based on this column as first preference.
Maximum of 2 "dots" are possible in a SerialNumber.

So `1.2.3.4` is not possible. Maximum Number may be `999` in any level of sequence. 
ie. `999.999.999` is the maximum possible sequence.

I tried by issuing a `ORDER BY SerialNumber`, it comes like

```
1
10
10.1
..
2
2.1
```

Just because of character sort , Instead of `2`, `10` comes after `1`.
Any idea of how it can be achieved.? As I need this in JDBC and in multiple queries ( Different modules) hoping to have this as generic as possible.

Comment: Get substrings of each numeric component and scale by a power of 10, then add them all, and sort.

Comment: `LPAD` `0` with every number inside.. so u can do a character sort.. example `1.1.1` as `001.001.001`

Comment: Will a regular expression help? Sorry am not good at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function to extract every number using `'.'` as delimiter and lpad with 0s. And call the function() in `order by`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FORMAT_MY_SERIAL(
    ORIG_SERIAL VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  FINAL_SERIAL VARCHAR2(15) := '';
  SERIAL       VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
  SERIAL                   := ORIG_SERIAL;
  WHILE (INSTR(SERIAL,'.') <> 0)
  LOOP
    FINAL_SERIAL := TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(SERIAL,INSTR(SERIAL,'.',-1)+1),'FM099')||'.'||FINAL_SERIAL;
    SERIAL       := SUBSTR(SERIAL,1,INSTR(SERIAL,'.',-1)-1);
  END LOOP;
  FINAL_SERIAL := TRIM(BOTH '.' FROM TO_CHAR(SERIAL,'FM099')||'.'||FINAL_SERIAL);
  RETURN FINAL_SERIAL;
END FORMAT_MY_SERIAL;
/
```

And this is an **example**:

```
WITH MY_TABLE AS
  ( SELECT '1.1.1' AS SerialNumber FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '10' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.2' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2.1' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.10.1' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2.1' FROM dual
  )
SELECT SerialNumber,
  FORMAT_MY_SERIAL(SerialNumber) as formatted
FROM MY_TABLE
ORDER BY FORMAT_MY_SERIAL(SerialNumber);
```

**Result:**

```
SERIAL FORMATTED
1      001
1.1.1  001.001.001
1.2    001.002
1.10.1 001.010.001
2.1    002.001
2.1    002.001
10     010
```

Comment: Looks like it supports any number of levels and number size, adjusting variable size(!)..

Comment: yeah.. need code change,just for format model, keep the number size  short n sweet, safely :) create a function based index, or save the same in table even! it is reusable..

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use a regex function to split each part for ordering.  Something like:

```
select serialnumber
from data
order by
    to_number(regexp_substr(serialnumber, '[[:digit:]]+')),
    to_number(regexp_substr(serialnumber, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, 2)) nulls first,
    to_number(regexp_substr(serialnumber, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, 3)) nulls first
```

Which will give you results like:

```
SERIALNUMBER                                                                    
-------------------------------
1.100                                                                           
1.100.10                                                                        
34.134.819                                                                      
36                                                                              
75.717                                                                          
256.749.864                                                                     
397                                                                             
428.13.647                                                                      
443                                                                             
713.768                                                                         
855.238
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table temp as select dummy from dual;

alter table temp add  val varchar2(20);

select * from temp;

insert into temp (val) values ('1');
insert into temp (val)values ('1.2');
insert into temp (val)values ('1.1.1');
insert into temp (val)values ('2');
insert into temp (val)values ('2.1');
insert into temp (val)values ('10');

select val
  ,decode(substr(val,1,instr(val,'.')-1),null,val,substr(val,1,instr(val,'.')-1))
from temp
order by     to_number(decode(substr(val,1,instr(val,'.')-1),null,val,substr(val,1,instr(val,'.')-1))),val
```